# 2-connected graphs that contain no even cycle have a very simple structure

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, graph-connectivity

I recently received as an exercise the statement « 2-connected graphs that contain no even cycle as a subgraph have a very simple structure. » I then had to describe that structure and prove it.

I did not really have a revelation about which direction to take so this is what I did. I know it is probably not correct at some point or that there might be a lot of theorems that I didn’t think of that would have made this easier :

Let $G$ be an arbitrary 2-connected graph that contains no even cycle as a subgraph.
Since $\forall H \subseteq G$, $H$ is not an even cycle, $G$ has no even cycle in its structure.
Also, due to $G$’s 2-connectivity, we know that :

1. $G$ cannot be a tree
2. $G$ contains no cutvertex
3. $G$ contains no bridge
4. $G$ contains at least one cycle (specifically an odd cycle in this case, I am not sure if this point 4 is correct/relevant to assume or not)

With this in mind, intuitively, I thought that $G$ had to be a graph whose structure can only contain odd cycles « glued to one another », meaning odd cycles that are joint by the edges they share.

But then, I showed that it is not possible for $G$ to be made of multiple odd cycles that share edges since, if two odd cycles share edges, there exists a cycle $C$ around the edges of $C_1 \cup C_2 \setminus X$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are the two odd cycles and $X:=C_1\cap C_2$ is the set of the edges they share, such that $C$ is of even length.

To show that $C$ is of even length, note first that $\lvert C_1\rvert$ + $\lvert C_2\rvert$ is even since it is the sum of two odd numbers.
Take P the path along the edges of X, let $v_1$ and $v_n$ be the endpoints of P. The path $v_1C_1v_nC_2v_1$ is the cycle $C$. $\lvert C\rvert = \lvert C_1 \cup C_2\setminus X\rvert$. We can also write this equation as $\lvert C\rvert = \lvert C_1\rvert - \lvert X\rvert + \lvert C_2\rvert - \lvert X\rvert = \lvert C_1\rvert + \lvert C_2\rvert - 2\lvert X\rvert$, which is clearly even.

Thus, this means that $G$ does not contain more than one odd cycle (since if it contains 2 or more, any pair of odd cycles induces an even cycle), which means that $G$ is itself an odd cycle.

Is this result correct and is this a valid proof ?

Comment: I believe the only graphs fulfilling your conditions are cyclic graphs with an odd number of vertices.  Any bridge would leave an even and an odd cyclic subgraph, and hence there can be no such bridges.  In short:  yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: Isn't it true, more generally, that a $2$-connected graph, in which no pair of vertices is connected by $3$ internally disjoint paths, must be a cycle graph? (Of course a graph with no even cycles can't have two vertices connected by $3$ internally disjoint paths.)

Comment: A 2-connectes graph can have pairs of vertices connected by 3 internally disjoint paths, just not all of them. Also, they contain at least a cycle but can very well be made of more than one cycle.

Comment: @maitrehihois Yes, a $2$-connected graph may contain any number of such pairs, even all of them. (Note that being $2$-connected in general doesn't mean not being $3$-connected.) But any such pair contradict the second condition: no even cycles. P. S. Your proof is correct, bof just helps you to make it a bit shorter

Comment: Oh yes I don't know why I wrote that. Is there a quick proof as to why 3 internally disjoint paths imply there is an even cycle ? Intuitively I would say that 3 internally disjoint paths define the frontiers of 2 cycles and one part of the frontier of those two cycles is shared. If none of these two cycles is even, this is basically the thing I describe at the end of my proof. Right ?

Comment: That's right. However another possible thinking is the following. If there are $3$ internally disjoint paths, then at least two of them have length of the same oddity, and therefore together form an even cycle

Comment: Oooh that's very nice. Thank you for all of this !